# how to place validation for phone number in android,"starts with +"?

Tags: android

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$");
          //Match the given string with the pattern
          Matcher m = p.matcher(numberstr);
          //check whether match is found 
          boolean numberFound = m.matches();
```

Answer (score 8):

1) If you want to validate a text field, so they can enter only phone numbers you need to put in XML

```
android:phoneNumber="true"
```

2) Or if you want to validate a phone number make use of the [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) class, and you can make use of the [MatchFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.MatchFilter.html) interface it provides to get the recognized phone numbers in the charsequence.